# How to solve "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tsl'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed python but didn't work. Then all of the following but when, I was supposed to import the following it didn't work.

```html
!pip install -U pip
!pip install tensorflow
 from tensorflow import keras
 from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Comment: Can you improve your question? What OS are you using? How did you install tensorflow? What was the output after your installed the tensorflow from the command-line?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to run pip install tensorflow in command